# Internet Explorer behavior as Mozilla Firefox or Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, cross-browser, xulrunner, google-chrome-frame

Is there a solution to get Internet Explorer to behave as Firefox or Chrome? I am looking for a solution that would not use css hacks. I mean maybe some scripts to force change all behavior of IE.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Can this program, which is completely different that this other program, act exactly like this other program?"

Comment: No.  It cannot.  That's not how software works.

Answer (score 4):

You can have your users download and install [Google Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe), then add this meta tag to your page head per the [Chrome Frame developer guide](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

Of course, this requires user action. You can't control what browser your users use, nor can you force a certain browser to act like another browser through your own code alone.

Comment: I would argue that this is only a theoretical approach...Also how easy is it to switch back and forth between real IE and Chrome if you were to convince your users that this was better than installing Chrome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry can't be done, this is one of the many joys of being a web developer.... Browser quirks :-)

Comment: Yeah =(, but I thought perhaps something came up that I do not know.

Comment: And let the whole world wait (с) Internet Explorer =)

Comment: It's painful to support browsers like IE6/IE7, but I think IE8 and IE9 seem to be ok :-)

Comment: For general web development no one should now support IE6, Google, M$ and Amazon don't so why should you. If the client insists, you also insist that they pay more..=)

Comment: Yes, every day i'm trying to convince my booss don't support IE6, but our Google analytics shows deplorable results. Around 38% of visitors under IE6. Costs of our region =(

Answer (score 1):

Nope. IE sucks because it sucks. Closest you get is something like [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) but it comes with limitations and drawbacks. It can't for example magically give IE full SVG or WebGL support but it can give IE better CSS selector support and fix some bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good experiences with combining these two libraries:
http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ & http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ to adjust for various css variances and newer html5 tags. Can't say if it'll solve any of the issues you have, and it may in some cases still require some css conditionals / hacks, but it'll most certainly iron out many smaller issues.

So I usually drop these into my header of any major project:

```
    <!-- Let's make IE6-8 bend to our will -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

[XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) and the [Mozilla ActiveX Control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm) can be combined to run [Gecko in IE](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2006/12/xule-what-if/).

**References**

- [Using wxWidgets in FireBreath](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/369235/Using-wxWidgets-in-FireBreath)
- [Deployment of NPAPI plugin with minimal user steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468708/1113772)
- [Browser Plugins vs Extensions: the difference](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/08/browser-plugins-vs-extensions-the-difference/)
- [XULRunner ActiveX Plugin](http://dxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/embedding/browser/activex/)
- [ActiveX Control for Hosting Netscape Plug-ins in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ActiveX_Control_for_Hosting_Netscape_Plug-ins_in_IE)