# Fix CSS and other issues in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Making websites that appear correctly in IE is a big problem. Is there any java script library to fix all CSS and other issues associated with Internet Explorer (7, 8, 9) and make it work like Google Chrome, Firefox?

Comment: unfortunately no, you have to tackle most issues as they come by. although for many things you will find various solutions around the internet.

Comment: This smells like a duplicate of [Internet Explorer behavior as Mozilla Firefox or Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900748/internet-explorer-behavior-as-mozilla-firefox-or-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE) to make the page render in standards mode instead of [quirksmode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)
2. Check out what [properties in CSS you can use](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) and what browser supports them
3. If you plan to use HTML5/CSS3 tech, then you should [check the property](http://caniuse.com/) and what browser is currently implementing these new tech
4. You can reset the CSS using a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to start off from scratch in your styles
5. If you need a stable ground to build on for your page, consider using a "base" style framework like Blueprint CSS's typography and forms CSS.
6. Use a toolkit like jQuery, Mootools, Dojo etc. This will speed up your JS development. But NEVER let JS do styling and style fixes. That's the work of CSS.
7. Ofcourse, never assume your design works at all. You must test on all available browsers, on the current version, 2 versions back, and on betas.

Answer (score 2):

One important thing to remember is that different browsers respond differently to errors. So make sure your HTML and your CSS pass the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) error free. That will go a long way in ensuring your site will look the same on different browsers.

Also, don't use quirks mode. Different browsers have different quirks!

Comment: W3C Validator is next to useless, not to mention the fact that HTML5 elements are going to cause it to fail anyway.

Comment: Who told you that? Tell them they were wrong. But don't take my word for it. Test it for yourself.

Comment: Last time I checked this was experimental http://validator.w3.org/nu/ If you stop and think about the HTML5 "release cycle", it will always be a chapter behind and focusing on "validation" is not the way to think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to some of the CSS3 styles, then I would suggest you look into [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no but you can check which properties are not supported in IE with caniuse.com

http://selectivizr.com/ or http://css3pie.com/ will help you but they both won't work if js is disabled.

Read this if you're using html5 http://html5doctor.com/how-to-get-html5-working-in-ie-and-firefox-2/

And what Joseph said.

You could always check the results with http://browsershots.org/ but it's just a screenshot so it won't give you an idea for example of how things behave when you click/hover on them etc.

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer is yes, you can target the older versions of IE using a combination of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Modernizr is now included in the HTML5Boilerplate package.

For more details of an HTML5Boilerplate approach to this:

[HTML5 Boilerplate, IE7 & 8](http://carlorizzante.com/2012/html5-boilerplate-ie7-8-less-and-how-to-make-those-things-effectively-work/)